# Does Kobayashi isometry map preserve complex geodesics?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables, geodesics

Let $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ are real geodesics in a domain $D$ and these two real geodesics are lying in the same complex geodesics, the question is, are $f\left(\gamma_1\right)$ and $f\left(\gamma_2\right)$ are in the same complex geodesics, where $f: D \longrightarrow \Omega$ is an isometric mapping.
note: (1) isometric map means it is bijective and preserve Kobayashi length.
(2) If the answer is difficult, please list some helpful reference.

Thank you

Comment: "A domain": is it endowed with a Hermitian / Kähler metric?

Comment: @YCor: there need not be any choice of Hermitian metric; the question is about the Kobayashi pseudometric, which in this question is assumed to be a metric, i.e. we assume Kobayashi hyperbolicity of the domain.

Comment: It would be useful then to say explicitly that the domain is endowed with the Kobayashi pseudometric before talking of its geodesics (and also that $D$ is a domain inside $\mathbf{C}^n$ for some $n$?).